# Mains transformer input overvoltage protection

Tags: transformer, mains, protection

You have a mains transformer with switchable inputs, 120V and 230V.

In case somebody switches the input to 120V and applies 230V (which cannot be mechanically prevented, reasonably), the whole assembly should not go up in flames. I want something well-defined to happen that protects the circuit. Blowing the fuse is acceptable.

I think there must be a simple, low BOM-count solution, but I cannot think of it.

Comment: I've not specifically tried this, but a ferroresonant transformer crosses my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fuse.

One step up: a resettable fuse.

If you don't want to rely on the transformer to saturate and blow the fuse, you can use a crowbar circuit.

Comment: Thanks. Why does the fuse blow in that scenario?

Comment: @MichaelB.Ortiz The transformer will saturate due to too high voltage-time-product and pull a very high (magnetizing) current, blowing the fuse.

Answer (score 0):

This is just barely an answer, but it seems too much for a comment:

You might consider an automatic 120/240V switching device.

There used to be, I think, components of this description... I only know of one, in my TDS460 oscilloscope: the power supply is a forward converter, in the style familiar from PC power supplies, with the optional voltage doubler style full-wave rectifier.  What they did is, there is a TRIAC-based switching module, that, depending on input voltage, automatically shorts out what would otherwise be the 120/240 switch.

Afraid I don't remember the part number, and I'm not going to take apart the equipment right this instant just to find it... but perhaps this jogs someones' memory.

I haven't seen such a component in catalogs, not to say they don't exist, but they are certainly in low demand these days, with the prevalence of APFC input SMPS.  Perhaps you would need to make your own anyway, as many more TRIACs are needed to switch a dual-primary transformer; or perhaps to prefer a relay or other switching means.  And at that point, perhaps the BOM count goes too high to bother.  Or perhaps the single module is too expensive anyway (it is odd that you only mention BOM count, not cost at all, but perhaps both are indeed a concern).

I would simply recommend an SMPS: they are widely available, highly effective, and are available with, or can be filtered to, low noise levels.  It's not clear what, if anything, you're ultimately doing with the AC output, maybe this isn't feasible or effective, but as it's a common use-case, I will leave it for completeness.